# Depricated rel="prerender" in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, prerender

I want to use the resource hint "prerender" ([W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/resource-hints/)) to speed up a website, but prerender is depricated in Chrome since v58. I read that NoState-Prefetch should be used instead ([Google Dev](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/07/nostate-prefetch)), but I don't find anything on how to use it.

Does anybody know how I can prerender a site with the current version of Chrome or how to use "NoState-Prefetch"?

I'm grateful for every suggestion. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: That page says “If you’re using Chrome 63 or later, your browser is already using NoState Prefetch for features like <link rel="prerender">.” Is something missing? What specific behaviors are you expecting or observing?

Comment: I read that too. If this would happen, I should see the resources of the next page being fetched by the browser (i. e. in Wireshark), but that doesn't happen. Only when I click on the link, the files are loaded and the pages is rendered.

Answer (score 1):

Prerender is not deprecated, in fact it's part of the [w3 standards](https://www.w3.org/TR/resource-hints/#dfn-prerender). Though the standards are clear in that the user agent SHOULD fetch, however later it describes that it May preprocess, and adds a point later that the user agent might decide not to do anything.

Chrome initiated the prerender resource hint, previously it meant that the whole page should be pre-rendered in a hidden renderer process, but currently chrome does NoState-Prefetch which is less powerful than a full render but should still save time - in case the browser actually do it.

You can take a look at the following [document](https://docs.google.com/document/d/16VCYGGWau483IMSxODpg5faZny1FJ6vNK2v-BuM5EhU/edit#) to dig deeper, into why chrome changed the implementation of prerender, and when/what does No-State Prefetch do exactly.

### To check that the browser did prerender locally:

- go to chrome://net-export/ ( this will export a log of all the network activities happening from all chrome windows, apps, and extensions)
- go to the website where you want to check prerendering, give it some time to idle and do the prerendering
- save the json file from the net export page, and load it into https://netlog-viewer.appspot.com/
- After its loaded, check the Prerender page found in the menu in the left side