# Is rel="prerender" deprecated in Google Chrome?

Tags: html, google-chrome, prerender, rel

I want to use `rel="prerender"` to prerender some pages. I have however read something about it being deprecated in Google Chrome and didn't find any trustworthy source on it.

Is `rel="prerender"` depricated in Chrome or does it still work?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52721308/depricated-rel-prerender-in-chrome

Comment: this doesn't answer my question @Josh Lee

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I took a time and find an answer right from Google. The prerender now does something different that the old deprecated prerender - NoState Prefetch. Here is the link with the statement:

[Google statement](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/07/nostate-prefetch)